# Crawl Images, Whole Web Pages and cache them

Tags: python

I am starting a project and wonder the relationship between the characters in images and the whole web page where the images reside.

I want to crawl some images and their web pages. I need to save the crawl result in local disk for further analysis. I wonder if there is any open source for this issue?

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but is image crawling legal? I want to use some crawled images from a website that has it's images accessible and downloadable, so no "hack" is used to obtain the images. The site also do not have a Copyright mark on images. Can I reuse those images?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of open source crawlers
http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&source=hp&q=open+source+web+crawler&aq=f&aqi=g9g-m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=77130048d7e0701a

Near top of the list are Java crawlers, and the Wikipedia article has some more as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) for this purpose. It is a simple java crawler that can be configured in a few minutes and you can use it for crawling images as well. You can also find an ImageCrawler example in the source codes.